# Save intermediate results in minimization problem

Tags: python, optimization, minimization, autosave

I am running a minimization problem using the next code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

Nfeval = 1

def objective_fnc(x):
    ....
    return y

def callbackF(x):
    global Nfeval
    print('{0:4d}   {1: 3.6f}   {2: 3.6f}   {3: 3.6f}   {4: 3.6f}   {5: 3.6f}'.format(Nfeval, x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], objective_fnc(x)))
    Nfeval += 1

res=minimize(objective_fnc, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', bounds=bnds, callback=callbackF, options={'disp': True})
```

I want to **save intermediate results** in a txt file in case the optimization process is stopped for any reason. The idea is to save only those results better than the previous one or better during the optimization process.

I have access to the variables and the objective function using the `callbackF` function defined previously. However, I am still trying to figure out how to save the best results when convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

class CallbackFunctor:
    def __init__(self, obj_fun):
        self.best_fun_vals = [np.inf]
        self.best_sols = []
        self.num_calls = 0
        self.obj_fun = obj_fun
    
    def __call__(self, x):
        fun_val = self.obj_fun(x)
        self.num_calls += 1
        if fun_val < self.best_fun_vals[-1]:
            self.best_sols.append(x)
            self.best_fun_vals.append(fun_val)
   
    def save_sols(self, filename):
        sols = np.array([sol for sol in self.best_sols])
        np.savetxt(filename, sols)
```

Here, you don't need ugly global variables and the callback saves each now found solution, i.e. a solution with a lower objective function value than the last found solution. Example usage:

```py
cb = CallbackFunctor(objective_fun)
res = minimize(objective_fun, x0=x0, callback=cb)

print(cb.best_sols)       # contains all your collected solutions
print(cb.best_fun_vals)   # contains the corresponding objective function values
cb.save_sols("dummy.txt") # writes all solutions to a file 'dummy.txt'
```

---

However, in case you really want to write all solutions to a file for each new found solution, you can modify the callback such that it calls `save_sol` after each new solution:

```py
import numpy as np

class CallbackFunctor:
    def __init__(self, obj_fun, filename):
        self.best_fun_vals = [np.inf]
        self.best_sols = []
        self.num_calls = 0
        self.obj_fun = obj_fun
        self.filename = filename
    
    def __call__(self, x):
        fun_val = self.obj_fun(x)
        self.num_calls += 1
        if fun_val < self.best_fun_vals[-1]:
            self.best_sols.append(x)
            self.best_fun_vals.append(fun_val)
            self.save_sols(self.filename)
   
    def save_sols(self, filename):
        sols = np.array([sol for sol in self.best_sols])
        np.savetxt(filename, sols)

cb = CallbackFunctor(objective_fun, "dummy.txt")
res = minimize(objective_fun, x0=x0, callback=cb)
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand the code. Firstly, when you called `cb = CallbackFunctor(objective_fun)` shouldn't you not pass also the argument `x` It seems you need when you define `def __call__(self, x):`

Comment: Another doubt I have, what happens with the variables if the execution of the optimization algorithm is interrupted, for instance with a blackout. In this case, the line `cb.save_sols("dummy.txt")` is executed at the end, after the minimization algorithm is finished. I would like to have that file saved during the iterations of the algorithm

Comment: @nekovolta No, you can think of `cb = CallbackFunctor(objective_fun)` as a special way of defining a function `cb`  by calling the class constructor. The special method `__call__(self, x)` makes the object `cb` callable like a function, i.e. you can simply call `cb(x)`. Note that `self` is not an argument of the method, it only states that it's a special method of the class and has access to all class attributes (best_sols etc).

Comment: @nekovolta Furthermore, you don't need to save the file during the iterations, since the callback collects all solutions even if the optimization is interrupted. Consequently, it's safe to call `cb.save_sols("dummy.txt")` after the optimization. However, in case you really want to save the file after each new found solution, you can easily modify the class.

Comment: I tried to simulate a blackout. I stopped the execution and close spyder. I reopen it and if I executed `cb.save_sols("dummy.txt")` the file is empty.

Comment: Please be more precise next time. "Stopping the optimization process" and "closing spyder" are two different things. The latter kills the python session and thereby all data is freed. Consequently, you can't access data from the previous python session... Having said that, I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you. I am sorry for my inaccuracy. My concern was more related, for instance, in a blackout when the simulation and the PC would turn off.