# How to return best guess of scipy minimize, when when no solution was found?

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize

During my optimization, scipy often does not find a solution and simply return my initial guess. I would rather use the best values found so far rather than my initial guess.

```py
> results = optimize.minimize(optimize_me, x0, method='BFGS', jac=True)
> results.success
False
> results.x == x0
True
```

Like this `optimize_me(x0) == results.fun`. But I would prefer `optimize_me(results.x)`/`results.fun` to be the lowest value found, even when no solution was found.

Comment: You can use a callback similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68284365/save-intermediate-results-in-minimization-problem/68288194#68288194).

Comment: I tried using callbacks before. Something must have changed with scipy, as the callbacks are never called. The parameters of CallbackFunctor never change, because `__call__` is never called.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example in which `minimize` fails for you?

Comment: I don't really undertand why it fails in my code. With a minimal example, it always works :(, looks like the error might be somewhere else. In my code `optimize_me` is called multiple times, but the callback is not triggered. But in the minimal example it all works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `callback`

```
func = lambda x: np.cos(14.5 * x - 0.3) + (x + 0.2) * x
x0=[1.]

def print_fun(x):
    print("Current value: {}".format(x))

minimize (func, x0, method = 'BFGS', callback=print_fun)
```

This prints current value with each iteration as:

```
Current value: [1.05820172]
Current value: [1.09236336]
Current value: [1.09262207]
Current value: [1.09260106]

      fun: 0.4259196810917082
 hess_inv: array([[0.00477712]])
      jac: array([-1.2665987e-06])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 16
      nit: 4
     njev: 8
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([1.09260106])
```

You can modify the print function to your liking. However, not all optimization routine supports callback.